# complete metrizable subspace of a Hausdorff space is $G_\delta$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space and suppose $X$ is a dense subspace of
>   $Y$ having a complete metric $d$ on it ($Y$ itself need not be
>   metrizable). Prove that $X$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $Y$.

We have to show that $X$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $Y$. It is given that $\overline{X}=Y$ and $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space. By Baire Category theorem we can at most say that $X$ cannot be written as countable union of nowhere dense sets and also that countable intersection of open dense sets in $X$ is dense in $X$. But here I'm a little confused about how to relate the density of subsets of the dense set $X$ to show the result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can $Y$ have a complete metric and not be metrisable?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's ambiguously phrased, and you grouped it differently than it was meant. $X$ shall be a dense subspace of $Y$, and $X$ shall be completely metrisable. Of $Y$, nothing beyond it being Hausdorff is assumed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could be... In that case you're basically reproving part of Lavrentiev's theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Lavrentiev's theorem on extension on functions to $G_\delta$'s:

If $f:A \to Y$ is continuous and $Y$ is complete metric and $X$ is a space, there is a subset $\overline{A} \supseteq B \supseteq A$ and a continuous $\bar{f}: B \to Y$ that extends $f$ and such that $B$ is a $G_\delta$.

In this case we can apply it to the embedding of $X$ into $Y$.

Comment: Is there a method more accessible using the idea I suggested above?